# python- Solving Round Table (ZCO,2012)

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

> N knights are sitting in a circle. Making a dessert for knight i costs C[i]. Find the minimum cost such that for every pair of adjacent knights, at least one gets his dessert. N ≤ 10 ** 6.

Input

> There are 2 lines of input. The first line contains a single integer N, the number of seats at the table. The next line contains N space-separated integers, each being the cost of the dessert of a Knight, listed in counterclockwise order around the table.

Output

> The output should be a single line containing a single integer, the minimum possible cost for you, the chef.

Problem reference:https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/problems/ZCO12004
.I have tried this using DP, my code

```
n=int(input())
a=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
def ram(x):
 m=x[0]
 k=0
 for i in range(2,n):
  if k==0:
    m+=min(x[i],x[i-1])
    if min(x[i],x[i-1]) ==x[i]:
     k=1
    else:
     k=0 
  else:
    k=0 
    continue
 return m 
b1=ram(a)
a.insert(0,a[n-1])
a.pop(n)
b2=ram(a)
print(min(b1,b2))
```

But unfortunately, this is a wrong answer, please find the fault.It is advised to consider time complexity, less than 1 sec.
edit:

```
n=int(input())
a=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
cost1=cost2=[]
if n==1:
 print(a[0])
elif n==2:
 print(min(a[0],a[1]))
else:
 cost1.append(a[0])
 cost1.append(a[1])
 for j in range(2,n):
  cost1.append(a[j]+min(cost1[j-1],cost1[j-2]))
 cost2.append(a[n-1])
 cost2.append(a[n-2])
 for k in range(2,n):
  cost2.append(a[n-k-1]+min(cost2[k-1],cost2[k-2]))
 print(min(cost1[n-1],cost2[n-1]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution to this problem basically has to take care of 2 states.

Consider you are currently at index i. Now you have to decide whether you want to select the element of index i in your final sum.

The states are as follows:

1) If you decide that element at index i should included in final sum, then it does not matter that the element at previous index, i.e. i-1, is included or not.

2) If you decide that element at index i should not be included in final sum, then it is mandatory that the element at previous index, i.e. i-1, is included.

In your solution, you are taking care of only state 1, but not of state 2. So you will have to maintain 2 variables for optimal intermediate answers at each index.

Here is the sample code:

```
function calculate(int arr[], int start, int end){

    dp[start][0] = arr[start];
    dp[start][1] = 0LL;

    for(int i=start+1;i<=end;i++){

        dp[i][1] = dp[i-1][0];  //State 2

        dp[i][0] = arr[i] + min( dp[i-1][1], dp[i-1][0] ); //State 1

    }

    return min( dp[end][0], dp[end][1] );

}
```

Note: dp array is a 2D array that stores the intermediate optimal answers.

dp[i][1] = Optimal answer by not including the element.

dp[i][0] = Optimal answer by including the element.